# Regex: How to expand regex for domain name to include domains of type a.b.c.d?

Tags: regex, subdomain

The following regex picks up most mail server names of the form mail.example.com

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.{1,}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,})
```

as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/dG6sH9/1).

How do we expand it such that it matches domains with one (or more) additional subdomains e.g.

```
b-app05-06.boldchat.com
ns126a.ba1.enops.net
NHQSDFEXCHUB01.nam.coair.com
ncsmcexchub01.nam.coair.com
```

Comment: Please provide the environment and how you are using the regex.  Is it PHP? Show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the last subpattern into a non-capturing group and set a `+` quantifier:

```
\b[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+){2,}\b
```

EXPLANATION:

- `\b` - Word boundary
- `[\w-]+` - A character class that matches an alphanumeric or a hyphen
- `(?:\.[\w-]+){2,}` - a non-capturing group that matches 2 or more sequences of a literal dot and 1 or more alphanumeric characters or hyphen
- `\b` - Word boundary

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG6sH9/4)

Comment: [Your regex matches `---...---.--.--.---`](https://regex101.com/r/nE1kT1/1). PS: `{1,}` is `+`.

Comment: What about a domain like from mta2l1.trans.r.grouponmail.co.uk? In this case, we have the TLD (.co.uk). the domain (grouponmail), and three subdomains beneath.

Comment: Ok, I see the regex in the question was just some "bait" :) Re-written from scratch to match the examples given.

Comment: @Pyderman: does it work for you now? If you have more input to test, please use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) to share.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it shorter:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ3jA2/1)

Comment: Thanks. What about a domain like from mta2l1.trans.r.grouponmail.co.uk?

Comment: @Pyderman it does match that domain
@sp00m Yes that's a problem indeed, you can get the dash out like this `((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\-|\.))+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,})$`

Answer (score 2):

First, here is how to match one domain (given your examples):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

A tld gets matched with:

```
[a-z]{2,}
```

Now, you can have several domains separated by dots, followed by a tld:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ttmX76B2mHP4_PEA)

---

If you need to match domains composed by at least 2 subdomains + tld:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.){2,}[a-z]{2,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qznlaUaoUXNPFhp-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Some tld's are of the form .co.uk though, and I am looking to handle tld + domain + any number of subdomains

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? Mine matches such domains already, as well as [@MathieuDavid's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30777086/1225328).

Comment: By handle I mean match, If I try Thanks. If I try mta2l1.trans.r.grouponmail.co.uk with your regex, it matches only from trans across to the end of the tld.

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of regex recursion if your engine support it (PCRE compatible one usually) [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aR2xI3/3)

This regex would work for any number of subdomains and allow you to capture the inner domain.

`(([\w-]+)[.](\w{2,}$|(?1)))` in details:

- `(([\w-]+)[.]` start the whole capture for recursion, then start the capture for the leftmost subdomain followed by a dot.
- `(\w{2,}$|(?1)))` Alternation, try to match the tdl (end of match) or repeat the pattern.

You have the host in second capture group and it's domain in the third capture group. and the whole match in the first capture group (see the substitution pane in the demo)

Comment: It actually depends on the regex flavor the OP is using.

Comment: @sp00m Indeed , added a precision about it in the answer